# css grid - dynamic number of columns matching auto width

Tags: css, css-grid

I really don't think this should be quite so hard.  I have an unknown number of columns to display in a css grid.  I want all the columns to be the same width to match the content.  I want it to be min-content so the text will wrap when it gets too long.  I have tried many different variations.  But essentially, this is what I think I want and not sure why the browser says "invalid property value" on the `grid-template-columns` line.

```
.flyer-container > div {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that one.  I do not want to wrap any columns.  All columns need to stay on the first row.

Comment: The linked answer states quite clearly that what you want to do is not possible without stating a minimum width...hence it's a duplicate.

Comment: *"Unfortunately, with automatic repetitions, the minimum length cannot be auto, min-content or max-content alone, because that is forbidden in the specification."*

Comment: Aw, that's a bummer.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Found a better dupe which I've also linked.

Comment: If anyone is curious, I ended up doing this and making it work for my situation: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 200px));`